# Export current monitor settings

Tags: xorg, display, configuration

Is there a way to 'export' the current display configuration? We just need to export the configuration to an Xorg.conf file so that we can import it to another computer (deployment).

The active configuration seems to be saved elsewhere than /etc/X11/xorg.conf

The monitors are working on the PC and have been set up using the 'Display' configuration tool in the System Settings. We're using 12.04.

Comment: What graphics card and driver are you using? Unfortunately, some Nvidia (with `nvidia` driver) and AMD/ATI (with `fglrx` driver) have specific tools to do this.

Comment: It's an Intel card, we just need to know where the current display settings get saved (resolution, ...) so we can "export" them (import into another computer).

Comment: In case you use KDE, it's in `/home/gert/.kde/share/config/krandrrc` (per user) and `/etc/kde4/krandrrc` (system-wide)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the latest versions of Ubuntu [don't use an xorg.conf file anymore](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1437980).
gertvdijk makes a good point, if you want to use a file to automatically configure your display setup it might be important to know what kind of card you have.

There *might* be a rather universal solution to this. [Nvidia](http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?70722-NVIDIA-s-302-Linux-Driver-Finally-Has-RandR-1-2-1-3) and Intel support configuration of your displays through `xrandr`, meaning that if you could (i) save your settings to a file and (ii) automatically set that file as the defaults, you're good to go.

For (i), you can use `arandr`. Just `sudo apt-get install arandr` and set your configuration. Through File > Save as you can save the configuration as a shell file. For (ii) you could of course load the bash file at boot, but this is an ugly solution I think.

You sound like you know what you're doing, deploying computers and all, hopefully this can give you a push in the right direction. If it does helps, please append this post to briefly explain what you have done to get this to work.

If memory serves me right, Nvidia allows importing and exporting of the monitor configuration through `nvidia-config`. At least it did before they started supporting `xrandr`. This might also be of use...

Answer (score 1):

I did change layout in VMware, issuing a command, unfortunately forgot how (is not an action limited to VMware, but it was useful there).

I am currently looking into this and stumbled upon this Ubuntu thread.

Anyway, my input is just that xorg.conf is still useable in most distributions and desktop environments

xorg.conf is (usually split into various files under /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d directory (that might not exist).

I think it depends on your desktop system how much of the config files it leaves.

Xorg falls back on some system defaults but also probes the hardware and can run with almost no config files. And the core system might not have much from the Xorg package at all.

Using X11 config files is still very useful if you want to change system defaults for desktop like keyboard layout for more than just the user and often more persistent that changing desktop settings (xfce, kde, gnome or whatever).

On many systems (that got man pages installed) you can issue a "man xorg.conf" from a terminal/console for info.

If your system have Xorg issuing command "xorg -configure" in a blank console (no desktop) should save a ~/xorg.conf.new and you can load config into X with "X -config ~/xorg.conf.new" .. That will only load a basic xorg and not xfce kde etc. but it's just to give an idea about basic X stuff. xorg.conf.new can give some basic idea about how some hardware is configured though. (Usally best just to let system use default values). "X --configure" is dependant on Xorg being installed, but most systems still read config files if they exist.